# Page content hiding behind the header menu. How do i fix it?

Tags: php, html, css

I am trying to use the following header menu template across my website. unfortunately, the menu hides the top part of my page content. I am a newbie. Please help. I tried, removing z-index, adding bottom margin, noting works.

The header.php code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>CodePen - Responsive Hamburger Menu</title>
</head>
<body>
<!-- partial:index.partial.html -->
<header class="header">
      <a href="" class="logo">
      <img src="https://placeholder.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/placeholder.com-logo1.jpg"
          class="logoimage"/></a>
      <input class="menu-btn" type="checkbox" id="menu-btn" />
      <label class="menu-icon" for="menu-btn">
        <span class="navicon"></span>
      </label>
      <ul class="menu">
        <li class="contactme"><a href="#work">Contact Me</a></li>
        <li class="aboutme"><a href="#about">About Me</a></li>
        <li class="projects"><a href="#careers">Projects</a></li>
        <li class="Home"><a href="#contact" class="Home">Home</a></li>
      </ul>
    </header>
<!-- partial -->

<style>
body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background-color: #fffceb;
  }
  
  a {
    color: #000;
  }
  
  /* header */
  
  .header {
    background-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.1);
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 3;
  }
  
  .header ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #fff;
  }
  
  .header li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 20px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  
  .header li a:hover,
  .header .menu-btn:hover {
   background: rgb(255, 245, 246);
   color: rgb(247, 133, 152);
  }
  
  .header .logo {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    font-size: 2em;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  
  /* menu */
  
  .header .menu {
    clear: both;
    max-height: 0;
    transition: max-height .2s ease-out;
  }
  
  /* menu icon */
  
  .header .menu-icon {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    padding: 28px 20px;
    position: relative;
    user-select: none;
  }
  
  .header .menu-icon .navicon {
    background: #333;
    display: block;
    height: 2px;
    position: relative;
    transition: background .2s ease-out;
    width: 18px;
  }
  
  .header .menu-icon .navicon:before,
  .header .menu-icon .navicon:after {
    background: #333;
    content: '';
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    transition: all .2s ease-out;
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  .header .menu-icon .navicon:before {
    top: 5px;
  }
  
  .header .menu-icon .navicon:after {
    top: -5px;
  }
  
  /* menu btn */
  
  .header .menu-btn {
    display: none;
  }
  
  .header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu {
    max-height: 240px;
  }
  
  .header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon .navicon {
    background: transparent;
  }
  
  .header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon .navicon:before {
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
  }
  
  .header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon .navicon:after {
    transform: rotate(45deg);
  }
  
  .header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon:not(.steps) .navicon:before,
  .header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon:not(.steps) .navicon:after {
    top: 0;
  }
  .logoimage{
      width: 130px;
  }
  
  /* 48em = 768px */
  
  @media (min-width: 48em) {
    .header li {
      float: left;
    }
    .header li a {
      padding: 20px 30px;
    }
    .header .menu {
      clear: none;
      float: right;
      max-height: none;
    }
    .header .menu-icon {
      display: none;
    }
    .Home{
        order: 1;
    }
    .projects{
        order: 2;
    }
    .aboutme{
        order: 3;
    }
    .contactme{
        order: 4;
    }
  }

  @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
.menu{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
}
  }
</style>  
</body>
</html>
```

Then I have a index.php where I include this header.
The style related to my index.php is

```
body {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

.formular input:disabled {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}

.hint {
  color: grey;
}

.title {
  font-weight: bold;
}

p.subtitle {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.requiredSymbol {
  color: red;
}

.formular input[readonly="readonly"] {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}

form.formular,
.validationEngineContainer {
  /*background-color: #FFFFFF;*/
  font-family: tahoma, verdana, "sans-serif";
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #a5a8b8;
  width: 700px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.formular fieldset {
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #b5b8c8;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

Comment: You are going to encounter some formatting issues if you are really nesting a complete HTML document (with open and close `<html>`,`<head>`,`<body>` tags) inside another html document, which I presume also has those HTML tags that can be used only once in an HTML file.

Comment: When it comes to CSS, the precedence (order in which rules are declared) matters. It will be challenging for Stack Overflow users to help you with this issue without seeing how the index and header documents become one HTML document.

Comment: Could [edit] the question to show us what your page's markup actually looks like when the header file is included in the index file?

Comment: Hi @tshimkus  thank you so much for your help. I took your suggestion and removed open and close <html>,<head>,<body> tags from the header.php. uploaded in server and worked like a charm. I know it's not perfect but served my purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Your header css should have a position:relative. And you can add some margin to add distance from whatever is in the body.
Example shown below:

```
.header {
    background-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 10%);
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 3;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```